# How do I get the parent form from a child form in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, forms, parent

I have a VB form which may be called by a number of forms. Upon exiting this child form, I want to restore the calling form but I cannot seem to figure out how to determine which form called it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kind of depends on how you're calling the child form.  Really you just need to pass in a reference to Parent.  Maybe a property on the child that you set via the constructor

Comment: Why would you need to restore anything in the first place? Why not just call ShowDialog, in which case the second form will block access to the first until it closes, at which point the first form is activated again. If you really must hide the first form, that form should simply handle the FormClosed event of the second form and reshow itself. The second form should have no need to know which form displayed it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tagging for parent forms (maybe a global array) which you will update the value every time you open a child form. You just have to remember which form is which on the tagging you will make.

Maybe you can try this-
Module with form tagging:

```
 Module Module1
    Public parentForms(2) As String
    'parentForms(0) - parent form of Form 1
    'parentForms(1) - parent form of Form 2
    'parentForms(2) - parent form of Form 3

    Public Sub openParentForm(ByVal ParentTag As String)
        If ParentTag {use the notequal operator} "" Then
            Select Case ParentTag
                Case Form1.Tag
                    Form1.Show()
                Case Form2.Tag
                    Form2.Show()
                Case Form3.Tag
                    Form3.Show()
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Form1:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Tag = "Form1"
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    parentForms(1) = Me.Tag
    Form2.Show()
    'Dont use .Close as the Parent Form will be disposed and the whole application will exit
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    parentForms(2) = Me.Tag
    Form3.Show()
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Call openParentForm(parentForms(0))
End Sub
```

End Class

Form2

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Tag = "Form2"
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        parentForms(0) = Me.Tag
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        parentForms(2) = Me.Tag
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Call openParentForm(parentForms(1))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form3

```
Public Class Form3
    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Tag = "Form3"
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        parentForms(0) = Me.Tag
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        parentForms(1) = Me.Tag
        Form2.Show()
        Me.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form3_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Call openParentForm(parentForms(2))
    End Sub
End Class
```